# Pieslice label is not visible in google pie chart if its proportion is small, can I make it visible?

Tags: google-visualization

This is my code snippet...
there is three pie slices in pie chart, but only two labels are visible

```
  var options = {
      is3D: true,
      fontSize: 7, 
      backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
      legend: 'none', 
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      pieSliceTextStyle: { bold: true, color:'black'}, 
      tooltip: {
          textStyle: { fontSize:  12 }
      },
      slices: {
          0: {color: '#e76442'}, 
          1:{color: '#ffc100'}, 
          2:{color: '#348be7'},
      } 
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no data shown my assumption is that the 3rd value is too small so there is no place for it. It is not rendered at all.

One option is to rotate pie chart so missing value get more width to be displayed. For example adding option:

```
pieStartAngle: 90
```

See also example [Rotating a Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#rotating) from google docs. On the left chart word 'Italian' is not visible. On the right chart it is visible after rotation.

Otherwise I don't see option to get it visible.

Comment: thank you so much for your help but It is not working. :( and one more problem tooltip is visible inside piechart, I want to show it outside, as shown in example of google pie-chart.