# Google pie chart force rendering of "minor" labels outside the pie

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've already researched a lot about google pie charts and hidden slice labels but didn't find anything with the labels outside the slices, so I'm hoping there is another solution than [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929851/pieslice-label-is-not-visible-in-google-pie-chart-if-its-proportion-is-small-ca) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417009/google-pie-chart-not-showing-all-data-rows) [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752518/google-charts-show-empty-items-in-legend).

I generate a lot of different chart types and for better readability I customize pie (doghnut) charts so they show their labels outside the slices, connected with lines. Now as seen in other questions google charts will just hide the slice label if there is no room for it or if the value is too small, which is unacceptable for me and why I wanted to show them outside where there should be enough room.

Still google charts dislikes "minor" data values and just doesn't show their label(s), even with `sliceVisibilityThreshold` set to `0`, is there any other solution with the following setup in mind? (You should see that the label "Far" for the violet slice is not rendered)

```js
var chartData = {
    "options": {
      "legend": {
        "position": "none"
      },
      "pieHole": 0.5
    },
    "data": [
      [
        "Label 1",
        "Label 2"
      ],
      [
        "Foo",
        33059
      ],
      [
        "Bar",
        57893
      ],
      [
        "Baz",
        8135
      ],
      [
        "Boo",
        12211
      ],
      [
        "Far",
        3740
      ],
      [
        "Faz",
        7219
      ]
    ]
  },
  ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');

var onLoadGoogle = function() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData.data);
  var chart = new google.visualization['PieChart'](ctx);
  var options = chartData.options;

  options.legend.position = 'labeled';
  options.pieSliceText = 'none';
  options.sliceVisibilityThreshold = 0;

  chart.draw(data, chartData.options);
}

window.google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
  packages: ["corechart"],
  callback: onLoadGoogle,
  nocss: true
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: No there hasn't been a solution a year ago, but I didn't check if they fixed it with never versions of the plugin.

Comment: still not fixed :(

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the [documentation for PieChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart), the `pieStartAngle` option can help to make space for some labels, though there is nothing that can be done if there is just not enough space.  This applies to both the default labels inside slices and the labeled legend option you are using.

You could also experiment with the `pieSliceTextStyle` and `legend.textStyle` to set the `fontSize` option to a smaller font.

Comment: So there's no other solution than in my "already suggested on SO" links. Your suggestion to change fontSize is not really a reliable solution in my case since I dynamically generate a lot of charts and I can never know how I have to adjust the size to make it work for all of them.

Comment: Actually, another idea is to order your items differently, so they end up in places that have enough space, but since your data is dynamic, that would be difficult.  Also, do you really need a PieChart?  A Column or Bar chart can be a better user experience, giving all bars more equal treatment.

Comment: Well I have no control over what chart is used and it's nearly impossible to convince the customer to just not use pie charts ;)